# Suppression of a ligature in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, ligatures, selnolig

I'm trying to reproduce an old book with XeLaTeX, and it has the [ct ligature](http://www.decodeunicode.org/data/c//XS/ct-Ligatur38711611.jpg) but not the [st ligature](http://typophile.com/files/Letter_st_6439.jpg). The `Ligatures=Rare` option seems to turn either both on or off. Is there a way to select which ligatures to use in XeLaTeX? I am using the Adobe Caslon Pro OTF fonts. I know the microtype package may be able to do this but it is not supported by XeLaTeX. Any help is appreciated.

Another question I have is, is it possible to change ligature options midway through a document? Or perhaps temporarily change the ligatures for one occasion?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is possible using [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico)'s [`selnolig` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig). It is on CTAN, and added to TeX Live and MikTeX. `selnolig` requires the document to be compiled with `lualatex`, but that wouldn't keep you from using your fonts; indeed, it is pretty similar to `xelatex` in usage.

(Btw, `microtype` is available for LuaTeX -- most of its functions -- but it cannot selectively deactivate ligatures. That's why `selnolig` was created.)

In this MWE, I load `selnolig` without either of its language options (it can deal with German and English), so it only gets rid of ligatures where I tell it to with `\nolig` rules. Since I don't have the Adobe Caslon Pro OTF fonts, I used Linux Libertine, which has the ⟨st⟩ and ⟨ct⟩ ligatures in its *Historical* set.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={Historical}}
    \setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{selnolig}
    \nolig{st}{s|t}
\begin{document}
best pact 
\end{document}
```

[image: output with selnolig]

Just as a comparison, here's the output without `selnolig`:

[image: output without selnolig]

`selnolig`'s main purpose is to automatically suppress ligatures across morpheme boundaries in German and English texts. [Its documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/selnolig) explains all about how to use it (and how to use `lualatex`, if you'd like some pointers there).

See also [New package, selnolig, that automates suppression of typographic ligatures](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/new-package-selnolig-that-automates-suppression-of-typographic-ligatures-beta) on Meta.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for that information. Worked flawlessly.

Comment: Is there no way to do this with xelatex? We have to use xelatex because of the publisher.

Comment: @StefanMüller With `selnolig`, definitely not. It depends on `lualatex` internally.

Answer (score 8):

@doncherry has already addressed your main question. I'll take a stab at your second set of questions:

> Another question I have is, is it possible to change ligature options midway through a document? Or perhaps temporarily change the ligatures for one occasion?

You're not very specific as to which of potentially very many ligature-related options you're looking to change, so my answer has to be quite broad. I think your best bet is to use the `\newfontfamily` command of the `fontspec` package to set up a "new" font (which could be the same as that set by `\setmainfont`...) and some font-related options. For instance, you could have the following setup in your document's preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures={Common,Rare}]{Adobe Caslon Pro}
\newfontfamily\acptemp[Ligatures={NoCommon}]{Adobe Caslon Pro}
```

You could then issue the commands

```
\bgroup
\acptemp
...
\egroup
```

inside the document's body to switch to a setup with all ligatures disabled within the scope of `\bgroup ... \egroup` -- while keeping the same basic font.

Comment: Sorry about the vague question. What I meant was, say I would like to enable the st ligature for a particular page, but keep it disabled for the rest of the document. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @Neo: Thanks for providing this clarification. The `selnolig` package currently works on an entire document; there's no option (yet!) to disable its operation for a certain range. For now, I'd suggest that you replace all instances of `st` with `\mbox{st}` to "hide" in the document's passage of interest. Doing so will "hide" the `st` character pair from the `\nolig{st}{s|t}` command. A bit kludgy, I'm afraid. :-(

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since it's only about a page it's not a lot of work. I have tried your package and it works great. Again, thanks for all the work and help!

Comment: @Neo - I've gone ahead and created the macros `\selnoligon` and `\selnoligoff`. As their names suggest, they serve to switch selnolig's macros on and off. (The default switch setting is, unsurprisingly, `\selnoligon`.) I've uploaded the files affected to the GitHub site; be sure to download both `selnolig.sty` as well as `selnolig.lua`. The user guide now features a subsection to mention this new functionality.