# How to print all ligatures in a given font?

Tags: fonts, ligatures

For comparison purposes (between fonts), is there a way to print all available ligatures in a given font? Where do those ligatures reside in the font map?

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106131/how-do-i-know-which-ligatures-are-used-in-my-document and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106345/which-ligatures-do-the-fonts-used-in-my-document-offer

Comment: @egreg Sorry. I had missed http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106345/which-ligatures-do-the-fonts-used-in-my-document-offer, which is close enough to my question for the latter to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find the ligatures available in (say) Computer Modern Roman 10pt

```
 tftopl cmr10
```

which will show

```
(LIGTABLE
   (LABEL O 40)
   (KRN C l R -0.277779)
   (KRN C L R -0.319446)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C f)
   (LIG C i O 14)
   (LIG C f O 13)
   (LIG C l O 15)
   (KRN O 47 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 77 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 41 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 51 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 135 R 0.077779)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 13)
   (LIG C i O 16)
   (LIG C l O 17)
   (KRN O 47 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 77 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 41 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 51 R 0.077779)
   (KRN O 135 R 0.077779)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 140)
   (LIG O 140 O 134)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 47)
   (LIG O 47 O 42)
   (KRN O 77 R 0.111112)
   (KRN O 41 R 0.111112)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 55)
   (LIG O 55 O 173)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 173)
   (LIG O 55 O 174)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 41)
   (LIG O 140 O 74)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL O 77)
   (LIG O 140 O 76)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C k)
   (LABEL C v)
   (KRN C a R -0.055555)
   (LABEL C w)
   (KRN C e R -0.027779)
   (KRN C a R -0.027779)
   (KRN C o R -0.027779)
   (KRN C c R -0.027779)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C P)
   (KRN C A R -0.083334)
   (LABEL C y)
   (KRN C o R -0.027779)
   (KRN C e R -0.027779)
   (KRN C a R -0.027779)
   (KRN O 56 R -0.083334)
   (KRN O 54 R -0.083334)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C F)
   (LABEL C V)
   (LABEL C W)
   (KRN C o R -0.083334)
   (KRN C e R -0.083334)
   (KRN C u R -0.083334)
   (KRN C r R -0.083334)
   (KRN C a R -0.083334)
   (KRN C A R -0.111112)
   (LABEL C K)
   (LABEL C X)
   (KRN C O R -0.027779)
   (KRN C C R -0.027779)
   (KRN C G R -0.027779)
   (KRN C Q R -0.027779)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C T)
   (KRN C y R -0.027779)
   (LABEL C Y)
   (KRN C e R -0.083334)
   (KRN C o R -0.083334)
   (KRN C r R -0.083334)
   (KRN C a R -0.083334)
   (KRN C A R -0.083334)
   (KRN C u R -0.083334)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C D)
   (LABEL C O)
   (KRN C X R -0.027779)
   (KRN C W R -0.027779)
   (KRN C A R -0.027779)
   (KRN C V R -0.027779)
   (KRN C Y R -0.027779)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C h)
   (LABEL C m)
   (LABEL C n)
   (KRN C t R -0.027779)
   (KRN C u R -0.027779)
   (KRN C b R -0.027779)
   (KRN C y R -0.027779)
   (KRN C v R -0.027779)
   (KRN C w R -0.027779)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C c)
   (KRN C h R -0.027779)
   (KRN C k R -0.027779)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C b)
   (LABEL C o)
   (LABEL C p)
   (KRN C e R 0.027779)
   (KRN C o R 0.027779)
   (KRN C x R -0.027779)
   (KRN C d R 0.027779)
   (KRN C c R 0.027779)
   (KRN C q R 0.027779)
   (LABEL C a)
   (KRN C v R -0.027779)
   (KRN C j R 0.055555)
   (LABEL C t)
   (KRN C y R -0.027779)
   (LABEL C u)
   (KRN C w R -0.027779)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C A)
   (LABEL C R)
   (KRN C t R -0.027779)
   (KRN C C R -0.027779)
   (KRN C O R -0.027779)
   (KRN C G R -0.027779)
   (KRN C U R -0.027779)
   (KRN C Q R -0.027779)
   (LABEL C L)
   (KRN C T R -0.083334)
   (KRN C Y R -0.083334)
   (KRN C V R -0.111112)
   (KRN C W R -0.111112)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C g)
   (KRN C j R 0.027779)
   (STOP)
   (LABEL C I)
   (KRN C I R 0.027779)
   (STOP)
   )
```

where for example

```
   (LABEL C f)
   (LIG C i O 14)
   (LIG C f O 13)
   (LIG C l O 15)
```

tells you that (C)haracter `f` ligatures with (C)haracters `i` `f` and `l` to produce (O)ctal 14 13 and 15

so for example this command (bash syntax)

```
(echo "";tftopl cmr10 | egrep "     .LIG" | sed -e "s/.*O \([0-7]*\)./ [\\\\char\'\1]/"; echo "\\bye")| pdftex \\relax
```

produces

[image]

Comment: I'm not asking for a full solution, but could you give me a hint as to how would you go about printing all of them in an output file?

Comment: ...and what does `(LABEL O 13)` represent?

Comment: @Jubobs updated with a picture

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Great! Weird that Spanish punctuation, endash and emdash are considered ligatures!

Comment: @Werner Octal 13 is hex B decimal 11 which is is the ff ligature inOT1 encoding then you see later in the table that O 13 ligatures with i or l to make octal 16 and 17 the ffi and ffl ligatures

Comment: @Jubobs the fact that --- makes an emdash and ff makes an ff glyph are the same as far as TeX is concerned, similarly `? making an inverted ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That makes sense. Thanks again.