# Meaning of double --/^^/##

Tags: tex-core, catcodes

```
\catcode`| = 13
\def|{\item {--}}
\def\itemize#1{{\leftskip = 40 pt #1 \par}}

\itemize{
| First item
| Second item
}
```

The above example from [Latex Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Plain_TeX) and I do not know what functionality `{--}` in the itemize provides. Does it have a special meaning?

Also I am confused about the double caret (^^) notation used at the beginning of the `Catcodes` section such as `^^K` for superscript.

In another example there is a nested macro which is added below. It is said that double macro parameters **##n** expand to **#n**, is this always the case?

```
> %% Required package.
\usepackage{ifthen}

%% TeX function that generates the language commands.
\def\localedef#1#2{
  \ifthenelse{ \equal{\locale}{#1} }{
    \selectlanguage{#2}
    \expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname ##1{##1}
  }{
    \expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname ##1{}
  }
}

%% Selected language. Can be placed anywhere before the language commands.
\providecommand\locale{fr}

%% Language commands.
\localedef{de}{ngerman}
\localedef{en}{english}
\localedef{fr}{frenchb}
%% ...
```

It is good that this page is comprehensive in the sense that a lot of topics are mentioned; however some subtle points are not explained lucidly. I think I should refer to some other source maybe `TexBook` to better understand the inner workings of **TeX**. Is there a introductory level short tutorial on `TeX` that I can use before consulting a more advanced source?

Comment: the site works best if you ask one question at a time, on `--` ligatures see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106131/how-do-i-know-which-ligatures-are-used-in-my-document on `^^` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62725/the-notation-in-various-engines on `##`  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71632/why-do-paramaters-of-renewcommand-need-to-double-up-the-within-a-foreach/71633#71633

Comment: For the resources to learn TeX, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299858/101651.