# Enabling c_t and longs_t without enabling s_t ligatures

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ligatures, hoefler, selnolig

I'm using the `Hoefler Text` font in `xelatex` with long s:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Contextuals=Inner]{Hoefler Text}
```

[image]

But I want to use the `ct` ligature (it's from the `Rare` set):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Contextuals=Inner, Ligatures={Rare}]{Hoefler Text}
```

[image]

Oh no! `fontspec` has also replaced all of Hoefler's longst ligatures with st ligatures when loading ct ligatures from the `Rare` ligature set.

Is there a way to enable the (`Rare`) ct ligature from `Hoefler Text` without also enabling the (`Rare`) st ligature?  I tried to use the `selnolig` package to selective disable the st ligature (`\nolig{st}{s|t}`) but that also stops the longst ligature from being used.  I'm trying to produce text how people of the early 19th century were able to:

- Example #1: [Encyclopædia Britannia (5th edition), 1817](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:5th6thEdition.jpeg).

  [image]
- Example #2: The Minion Pro font correctly uses the longst and ct ligatures.

  [image]

Note:  People of the early 19th century didn't buy Minion Pro for US $199 (which is like us paying US $4.1 million), so I'd also rather not =)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: related: [suppressing certain ligatures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61042/suppress-certain-ligatures-generally) and [suppression of a ligature in xelatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86593/suppression-of-a-ligature-in-xelatex)

Comment: Hello Thomas! Please look at [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86593/suppression-of-a-ligature-in-xelatex](suppression of a ligature in xelatex) which was suggested by Nils. AFAIK, switching to `lualatex` is currently the only option available. Either way, that question asks basically for the same thing as yours. Tell us whether they are significantly different. If not, they can be marked as duplicate.

Comment: AFAICT, the option `Contextuals=Inner` (to generate long-s characters automatically in initial and medial positions) currently works with XeLaTeX but not with LuaLaTeX. If you want to enable the just the `ct` ligature but no other "rare" ligature, you can do so in **LuaLaTeX** using an OpenType feature file, but you'll use the automated use of long-s glyphs. For now, the `selnolig` package only does ligature *suppression; selective *enabling* of ligatures isn't (yet) one of its capabilities. :-(

Comment: IMHO the `Inner` feature is not an appropriate option for taking care of correct `s`/`ſ` placement. The underlying mechanism is indifferent to the complex conventions that govern `ſ` usage in a given cultural/historical context, and it's indifferent to the semantic issues that are involved as well. Using `Inner`, your output will be full of  `succeſſfully miſdirected Doomſday tranſformers from Peterſburg`. There's no alternative to entering the `ſ`s correctly in the first place -- which by the way is exactly what we have Unicode (and Xe/LuaTeX) for, right? `:)`

Comment: Thanks all for the _extremely_ helpful tips.  Unfortunately, LuaLaTeX won't be an option since my text only has the short form of `s` and I depend on the XeLaTeX option `Contextuals=Inner`.  I also only have `s` and `s` in my text and do not differentiate between `s` and `ſ` so `selnolig` is of no help -- `selnolig` is yet to support the feature to _selectively_ enable the `ſ_t` ligature.

Comment: One way LuaLaTeX could be an option is if I write my own feature file repeating all the "Inner" rules for substituting `s` with `ſ` and then selectively enabling the ligature `c_t`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest way I ended up achieving the desired result was by keeping `XeLaTeX` with the `Contextuals=Inner` feature and replaced all occurrences of `ct` (which occurs far less frequently than `ſ`) with a command to substitute in a `c_t` ligature:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\hoefler[Ligatures={TeX,Common},Contextuals=Inner]{Hoefler Text}
\newfontfamily\rareliga[Ligatures={TeX,Rare}]{Hoefler Text}
\newcommand{\ct}{\rareliga{}ct{}\hoefler}

\begin{document}
\hoefler
The side attra\ct{}ion for most spe\ct{}ators was the mustard
\end{document}
```

[image: The side attraction for most spectators was the mustard.]

Not the most elegant way, but it works.  I'll go off now and start adding ligatures to Latin Modern.

Comment: I'd prefer `\newcommand{\ct}{{\rareliga ct}}`.

Answer (score 5):

@tohecz: Thomas's Q is closely related to the questions I referred to, but it seems he's suffering from a problem that's not addressed in these.

> I tried to use the selnolig package to selective disable the s_t ligature `(\nolig{st}{s|t})` but that also stops the longst ligature from being used.

If I understand correctly, you're expecting `selnolig` to differentiate between an `s` and `ſ`. You're not providing an MWE, but I'm assuming that in your case `selnolig` just can't differentiate between the two because *you* don't -- I guess your text only has `s` and `s`, so there's nothing `selnolig` could do for you.

Educated guess: entering your `s`s correctly is going to produce decent results.

[image]

- `selnolig` disabled. Minion Pro, all available `ſ_` ligatures as well as `c_t` and (inappropriate?) `s_t` are present.

[image]

- `selnolig` enabled. As above, only `s_t` is gone.

code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec,selnolig}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Rare]{Minion Pro}
\nolig{st}{s|t}
\begin{document}
The ſide attraction for moſt ſpectators was the mustard
\end{document}
```

How about the `ſ_t`? -- I don't have Hoefler Text, and Minion Pro doesn't have an `ſ_t` (technically, it does, it's just indistinguishable from unligated `ſ` `t`). But, for example, EB Garamond does, and it's not affected by `\nolig{st}{s|t}` (q.e.d.).

PS: if you're planning to reproduce early 19th century style, Hoefler Text (as well as Minion) will be a bad choice. It's off by at least two centuries, as is obvious from the two Encyclopædia Britannia pages (from the second one even more drastically so than the first). Have a look at a Hoefler's Didot instead, maybe [Old Standard](http://www.thessalonica.org.ru/en/oldstandard.html) or -- inexpensive and most appropriate -- [Miller](http://www.fontbureau.com/media/pdf/Miller.pdf) from Font Bureau.

### update

Looking at your own [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117327/7993) and your insisting on the idea that a mere `Contextuals=Inner` is going to suffice to produce correct results -- what [needs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117095/enabling-c-t-and-longs-t-without-enabling-s-t-ligatures/117111#comment260261_117095) to be stressed is that correct `ſ` usage is ***not as simple*** as »replace all non-final `s` by `ſ`«. I suggest you have a look at how the `ſ` was handled in the period/the culture whose style you're trying to reproduce. In what contexts was it used? When was a `s` used instead? Think compound-word word boundaries. What `ſ_` ligatures were available? Think, among others, `ſ_s`. In what contexts were which `ſ_` ligatures appropriate/inappropriate? Again, think compound-word word boundaries. What was considered a compound word in the first place? etc.

[image]

[image]

Further reading: http://babelstone.blogspot.ca/2006/06/rules-for-long-s.html

Comment: Great font recommendations @NilsL and you are correct; I only have `s` (and `s`) in my text and do not differentiate between `s` and `ſ` so `selnolig` is of no help.

Comment: a simple RegEx search and replace would fix that: intial-`s` and mid-`s` to `ſ`, plus a manual scan to revert the replacement for inappropriate cases (`ſ` at word boundaries in compound words).

Answer (score 0):

This is how to add automatic s → ſ substitution (when `Contextuals=Inner` is enabled) to the Latin Modern font:

```
feature hist {
  @notf = [a-e g-z];
  sub s' @notf by longs; # use "sf", not "longs f"
  sub longs longs' by s; # words don't end with longs
  sub f longs' by s;     # end with fs, not f_longs
} hist;

feature hlig {
  sub c t by c_t;
} hlig;
```

Now I just have to add appropriate ligatures for longs_i, longs_l, longs_longs, longs_longs_i, longs_longs_l and every ligature requested at http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Wishes_for_Latin_Modern.

Comment: don't forget `longs_s`, in case it's not in that list yet.

Comment: Short 's' has no ascender so `longs_s` will be kerned correctly, as will every other `longs_`x combination where x is any letter without an ascender.  If you insist on a dedicated `longs_s` ligature (which aren't used in the Britannica example), one already exists in the font as ß.  For the German's: under the `feature hist` section a `language DEU; sub longs s by germandbls;` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

It works, for me at least, to type `Style = Historic, Ligatures = Historic`

It is worth mentioning that my font is broken, it doesn't have any contextual capabilities. It is Hoefler Text Pro v1.201

Comment: Oh, sorry. `\fontspec[Style = Historic, Ligatures = Historic]{Hoefler Text Pro}` I'm on Windows by the way