# Force a single letter within \MakeUppercase to stay lower case

Tags: fonts, pdftex, uppercase

I need to write Heß in all caps. My publisher does not want XeTeX, so I have to find a good way to get the uppercase ß. The simplest way would be to just use the lower case ß instead. Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46525/preventing-makeuppercase-from-affecting-mathematics) I tried that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\newss{\MakeLowercase{ß}}
\MakeUppercase{He\protect\newss}
\end{document}
```

.. to no avail.

I cannot redefine `\MakeUppercase`. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're lucky, because `\ss` is a `\chardef` token both in the T1 and OT1 encoding.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\expandafter\let\expandafter\uSS\csname\encodingdefault\string\ss\endcsname

\begin{document}

\MakeUppercase{He\uSS}

\end{document}
```

This is a typographical abomination, but I believe you already know it.

[image]

Comment: What about this answer, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280408/what-is-the-history-of-the-%c3%9f-eszett-in-the-t1-encoding-of-computer-modern/281024#281024, that indicates the uppercase of eszett should be `SS`?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Yes, of course! But apparently the OP has to obey some *diktat*.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes. No, this is outdated. Since 2017, the uppercase ß is officially a letter again (in German at least). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E

Comment: @sheß Thanks for the update.  Tough to keep up with the Grammar Wars.

Comment: @egreg. Your solution works. Though sadly, the result is not copy-and-pasteable from the PDF. I guess I can live with that.

Comment: @sheß See the `accsupp` package for placing something different in typeset versus copy/paste.  See, for example of something similar, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233390/in-which-way-have-fake-spaces-made-it-to-actual-use/233397#233397