# How to get old-style ligatures in plain TeX

Tags: plain-tex, ligatures

I would like to typeset text with old-style ligatures like st, ct, is, es etc, but without the use of command sequences, e.g. street or construction instead of `\st reet` or `constru\ct ion` in Plain TeX. And use the long s. What do I need to do to get that? Thanks.

Comment: If you have a font with those ligatures you should not have to do anything in the tex markup.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle, any suggestion?

Comment: Not really (just a matter of looking through font catalogues, of course there are more options if you use xetex or luatex than classic tex so it depends a bit what tex engine you use) also I have to ask, why plain???

Comment: see here for one font with these ligatures http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117095/enabling-c-t-and-longs-t-without-enabling-s-t-ligatures

Comment: Lets say I like things my way, LaTeX's pretty good but I had some difficulties to change some things like spacing, formatting plus I very often need to install packages. I've tried LuaTeX but found it too hard, I'm currently considering switching to XeTeX. For me Plain TeX is like a minimalist approach that I can build my style upon it.

Comment: @BrianMayer What did you find “hard” about LuaTeX?  Everything just works as before.  It is not like you'd *have* to use the Lua interface.

Comment: Most people just install a distribution and the packages are all there. Unless you are extremely short of disk space, nothing else makes sense.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of changing the term "old English ligatures" to "old-style ligatures", since there's nothing specifically English about these ligatures: They were used on the European continent every bit as much as in England and her colonies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The OpenType font feature `hlig` provides these, so called, historic ligatures.  Instead of typing `ſ`, one could also use the `+medi` feature to have a normal `s` contextually replaced by `ſ`, so for instance the input `streets` would become `ſtreets` in the document.  Unfortunately, I don't have a font that provides `+medi`.  Perhaps some other user with a matching font can provide an example.

Typeset with either `xetex` or `luatex`.

```
\ifdefined\directlua
  \input luaotfload.sty
\fi
\font\1="Linux Libertine O:+hlig"
\1 ſtreet construction
\bye
```

> [image]

Here is a list of fonts, distributed with TeXlive 2015, which possess the `hlig` feature:

```
Accanthis ADF Std No3
Baskervaldx
EB Garamond 12
fbb
FreeSans
FreeSerif
Gillius ADF
Gillius ADF Cond
Gillius ADF No2
Gillius ADF No2 Cond
Linux Biolinum O
Linux Libertine Display O
Linux Libertine O
TeXGyrePagellaX
Universalis ADF Std
Universalis ADF Std cond
```

For the nerds, here is the `bash` command line for the above snippet (improved, thanks to Clea F. Rees):

```bash
IFS=$'\n';
for i in `fc-list | cut -d ':' -f 1 | grep /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/.*otf`; do
    if [ -n "`otfinfo -f "$i" | grep hlig`" ]; then
        otfinfo -a "$i";
    fi;
done | sort | uniq
```

Comment: If you pipe through `sort` and then `uniq`, you can eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the help, there is also the feature `hist` which contextually uses the historic form of some letters, so it places the long s for s automatically. Still, I'm not achieving the desired results due to otf problems, the apple's font book seems to import them with wrong ligatures. Tried with _Playfair Display_, on the website the ct and st glyphs are correct but when I install them they loose the arc, strange.

Comment: @BrianMayer Did you try `dlig` with Playfair Display?  It doesn’t have the `hist` feature (designers disagree somewhat in their interpretation of what the various features are for).

Comment: To resolve this problem I had to clean the font caches and reinstall the font, it seems like a common issue. Yes, with `dlig` ct and st ligatures are made correctly now, but to use long s you need to input it in the code manually. And yes they really disagree.

Answer (score 12):

Some 'traditional' fonts installed with TeX Live provide some or all of these ligatures and long s. How you access these depends on the way the font is configured since there's no 'standard' interface.

Although the following examples use LaTeX, this is just because this is what I'm most familiar with. The ligatures etc. are all defined at the font level and do not rely on the LaTeX packages. You just need to use the correct font at the TeX level, I believe. (But see not below about encodings.)

**Romande ADF** 'alternative' provides additional ligatures automatically and the long s may be accessed using `s*`.

[image: Romande ADF alternate]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{romande}
\begin{document}
\altstyle
As*s*ociated facts stray specious*ly.
\end{document}
```

**Venturis ADF Old** 'alternative' provides some additions, with the long s accessed using `s+`. (`s*` is used to access an alternate version of the regular `s`.)

[image: Venturis ADF old alternate]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{venturisold}
\begin{document}
\altstyle
As+s+ociated* facts stray s*pecious+ly.
\end{document}
```

There are also 'swash' styles you can do fancy things with. Venturis ADF itself includes end-of-word swashes, for example.

**Day Roman** is not part of TeX Live but can be installed using `getnonfreefonts-sys`, which automates the installation of additional fonts.

In this case, the relevant font family uses the long s by default and `s:` is required to access the regular s for use at e.g. the end of words. This family also provides additional ligatures.

[image: Day Roman s style]

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\rmdefault{dayroms}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Associated facts: stray speciously.
\end{document}
```

Most of these fonts use something other than the `OT1` encoding because this simply doesn't provide enough slots to spare any for fancy ligatures or alternate characters. I'm not sure how this works in plain, but the ability to use font encodings with 256 slots rather than 128 is pretty much essential for this, as there just isn't much you could sacrifice in `OT1` to make space for this kind of thing otherwise.

Note, too, that these things all work by hackery. Day Roman S does not use a standard `T1` encoding. I haven't looked at it. But it cannot be standard because it must be using a slot for the `s:` ligature and that is, of course, not a standard ligature in the `T1` encoding.

This means that there are some characters such that typesetting them will have unexpected results. There is *some* unrelated character such that including it in your document will unexpectedly produce the `ct` character or the long s or whatever.

It is therefore very important to read the documentation to check that you do not need characters whose slots have been used to accommodate the fancy, non-standard additions since you will not get any warnings about the unexpected output.

This is especially true if the font uses `T1` as `T1` has no free slots. Hence, even one additional character means *some* slot has been hijacked.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks everybody for the great answers, I learned a lot. I've found a great font, ideal for old books in my opinion, it's named *IM FELL DW Pica PRO* and can be found here: [Igino Marini Website](http://iginomarini.com/fell/the-revival-fonts/) alongside other great fonts. This one features historic forms and ligatures with `+dlig,+hlig,+hist` opentype font features and it works perfectly with XeTeX.

MWE:

```
\font\1="IM FELL DW Pica PRO:mapping=tex-text,+dlig,+hlig,+hist" at 12pt
\1 Associated facts stray speciously.

1234567890
\bye
```

Produces:

[image]

So no need to differentiate s from long s in the code. Thanks again.

Comment: IM Fell is also distributed with [TeXlive](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/imfellenglish).

Comment: Thanks @HenriMenke do you know how to enable its ligatures via the traditional `\font` in plain TeX?

Comment: Unfortunately, these ligatures do not appear in the OT1 encoded Type 1 version of IM Fell.  Thus they are not accessible from within `pdftex`.  You could still generate the Type 1 fonts from the OTF version yourself and sacrifice slots you don't need for these ligatures.  How to do this, is beyond my knowledge.  I'm sure @cfr can help you.

Answer (score 2):

kpfonts provides this option simply:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[veryoldstyle]{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
Associated facts: stray speciously.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You may want to show how the "long-s" glyph can be replaced with the "final-s" glyph, since the long-s glyph shouldn't be used at the ends of words and word fragments. (It looks like you attempted to do this in one instance; however, something seems to have gone wrong as the long-s glyph is shown.)

Comment: In later early modern editions, the second of a doubled 's' is also very often written in the modern way (while the first is the normal long-s). I always assumed this was to help distinguish it from a doubled 'f', but I've never looked into it.