# Removing "st" ligature in Humanist font

Tags: fonts, ligatures

By default, the [humanist](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/humanist) font joins "st" into a single ligature.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{humanist}
\begin{document}
\hminfamily Compare: straight versus s{}traight
\end{document}
```

I've tried to use the `microtype` package to remove this, but it doesn't seem to work with this particular one.  Any ideas how to change this throughout a document rather than doing it one instance at a time?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86593/suppression-of-a-ligature-in-xelatex might help.

Answer (score 3):

The [selnolig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig) package, which requires that documents be compiled under LuaLaTeX, may be your friend. It lets users define non-ligation rules via `\nolig` commands.

The package's main purpose is to set up rules to suppress ligatures selectively. However, it is easy to devise rules that suppress ligatures *globally*. For instance, to disable the long_s-t ligature globally, one just has to issue the instruction

```
\nolig{st}{s|t}
```

in the preamble of the document.

The package also provides a command called `\uselig` to override the action of a `\nolig` rule on a case-by-case basis.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{humanist}
\usepackage{selnolig}
\nolig{st}{s|t}        % suppress "st" ligature globally
\begin{document}
\hminfamily 
Compare: \uselig{straight} versus straight
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\uselig` doesn't seem to work for me - perhaps the version of the package I've got installed isn't the newest.  I'd prefer to use pdflatex rather than LuaLaTeX if possible, but otherwise this solution seems to work.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MartynQuick - The latest version of `selnolig` on the CTAN is 0.254. Which version of `selnolig` is installed on your system? I added the `\uselig` macro only quite recently, in the last couple of months or so. Incidentally, what makes you prefer pdfLaTeX over LuaLaTeX? I'm curious. (For the sake of full disclosure: I'm the main author of the `selnolig` package. I'm curious to know what keeps people from using it, or LuaLaTeX in general.)

Comment: The version of `selnolig` in TeXLive 2013 (recently installed on my Mac) is 0.218.  I'm used to using LaTeX (2e) and have done since shortly after its official release (1994-ish, I guess).  I've never used LuaLaTeX and don't really know what it is or why we need it - that's why I prefer pdfLaTeX.  (i.e., ignorance :-) )

Comment: @MartynQuick - I have a Mac as well. :-) Version 0.218 of `selnolig` is definitely several months old and thus predates the addition of the `\uselig` functionality. If you run `sudo tlmgr update --self --all` from a Terminal window, lots of LaTeX packages (including `selnolig`) will get updated. LuaLaTeX is, from a user's perspective, usually not very different from pdfLaTeX, even though the innards of the two underlying engines are indeed quite different. The user guide of the `selnolig` package gives an overview of the (hopefully few) things you may need to change in order to use LuaLaTeX.