# two t characters next to each other form one tt glyph

Tags: xetex, characters, linux, ligatures, libertine

I am using xelatex and linux libertine font. When I write in my text something that contains two `t` characters next to each other, such as "rotten", it changes these two `t`s into one `tt` character. It displays fine in PDF, but it is impossible to copy that or search for that in pdf.

How can I make it just simple two `t` characters next to each other?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4397/15925 help?

Comment: unfortunately it works only in pdftex

Comment: I think I might have found a solution, I added \setmainfont[Ligatures={NoCommon, TeX} and I can now search for tt

Comment: How about `ro{t}{t}en`, to avoid the ligature?  Even `ro{t}ten` should work.

Comment: Is using LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX an option for you? It looks like words containing the `tt` ligature remain searchable if the file is compiled by LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I use sharelatex, they only support latex, pdftex and xelatex

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes - While writing `rot{}ten` or `ro{t}{t}en` to break up the `tt` ligature works under pdfLaTeX, this method does *not* work under either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. :-(

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes using `{t}` doesn't always work under tex/pdftex either (it depends on details of linebreaking) early editions of the TeXbook suggested that but it was chnaged to suggest using \kern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the Ligatures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={NoCommon}]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}

\Huge rotten

\end{document}
```

Comment: This will also inhibit probably wanted ligatures, such as `fi`, `fl`, `ffi` and `ffl`.

Comment: that is obvious ...

Comment: Maybe not for everybody.

Answer (score 12):

If XeLaTeX is the only format that satisfies your typesetting needs -- in particular, if you can't use LuaLaTeX -- you have two options for suppressing the `tt` ligature while not also turning off all "common" ligatures entirely:

- Insert what TeX calls an *implicit kern* (of zero width) between the two `t` characters:

  ```
  rot\kern0pt ten  % note: no space between "\kern" and "0pt"
  ```
- Insert what TeX calls an *explicit kern* (also of zero width) between the two `t` characters:

  ```
  rot\/ten, rot\kern 0pt ten  % note the space between "\kern" and "0pt"
  ```

  The "italic correction" `\/` is a type of explicit kern. By the way, the italic correction method will not give a satisfactory result if the word in question is, in fact, typeset in *italics*.

Note that this will have to be done separately for each and every instance of "tt".

Final note/comment: The fact that words containing the `tt` ligature can't be searched in the pdf file if it's compiled via XeLaTeX could be a *bug* in the implementation of `Linux Libertine O` under XeLaTeX. First, words that contain the more common "Common" (pun intended) ligatures `ff`, `fi`, `fl`, and `ffl` *are*, in fact, searchable if the document is compiled via XeLaTeX. Second, the font family `Palatino nova` also features the `tt` ligature. When I compile the MWE below with `Palatino nova` instead of `Linux Libertine O`, I encounter *no difficulties* searching for words that contain the `tt` ligature (or, for that matter, words that contain the `ff`, `fi`, `fl`, `ffi`, and `ffl` ligatures).

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Common}]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
implicit kern (\verb+rot\kern0pt ten+): rot\kern0pt ten \& \emph{rot\kern0pt ten}

explicit kern (\verb+rot\/ten+): rot\/ten \& \emph{rot\/ten}

\verb+ro{t}{t}en, rot{}ten+: ro{t}{t}en, rot{}ten --- tt ligature still there!)
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, luckily I don't need any ligatures (or at least for now) so for now I will just go with <code>ligatures=nocommon</code>

Comment: @George - By disabling *all* common ligatures, you risk getting inferior typographic results for words that contain the character groups `ff`, `fi`, `fl`, `ffi`, and `ffl`.

Comment: @Mico Of course if XeLaTeX actually can't keep texts with ligatures searchable then you basically have to decide whether you want ligatures or a PDF that you can search. Manually disabling *one* ligature means you have one ugly word and one that you can search for. Often you don't know in advance what specific word you will be searching for.

Comment: @Christian - I'm afraid my answer may not have been as clear as I meant it to be: When using `Linux Libertine O` as the main text font, XeLaTeX currently *does* allow searches for words that contain the ligatures `ff`, `fi`, `fl`, `ffi`, and `ffl` -- but not for words that contain the `tt` ligature. I honestly don't know if this is a bug in the font's specification or XeLaTeX (or both...).

Comment: your comments `% note: no space between "\kern" and "0pt"` seem to imply that there is a difference if you put a space after `\kern` but there is none, that space would never be tokenised, as it follows a command name, so it will not affect anything. (also an implicit kern is one implicitly added by the font metrics `\kern` and `\/` make explicit kerns (as they are explicit in the markup) (not that these terminology quibbles affect the answer)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - The distinction between *implicit* and *explicit* kerns is straight from the second double-dangerous-bend item on p. 455 of the TeXbook. Please advise if you think I somehow misinterpreted the following sentence: "... if you look closely, `\kern2.0` denotes an implicit kern of 2 pt, and `\kern 2.0` denotes an explicit kern of the same magnitude." I've taken this statement to mean that the space between `\kern` and `2.0` does matter...

Comment: @Mico that is describing the `\showbox` output in the log file. If you add a kern with `\kern1pt` then it shows in the log as `\kern 1pt` if the font tfm metric adds a kern between between two letters _implicitly_ then (classic) TeX log file will show `\kern1pt` without a space. The space after `\kern` in the input file can't really matter as it is lost before TeX even recognises that the instruction is a kern.

Comment: @Mico Wow, that's one of those bugs where you wonder how complicated it must have been to enable them to happen :)

Answer (score 11):

If you just want to disable the tt ligature without disabling the others and don't want to manually add a kern each time, you can use the xetex charclass mechanism.

I don't seem to have the font so I disabled ff in arial instead, also I inserted a 10pt kern rather than 0pt, to make it more obvious.

[image]

Note in the second line ff is separated but the fi ligature works,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
\showoutput


ffoo difficult safe

\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\newXeTeXintercharclass\fchar
\XeTeXcharclass`f=\fchar
\XeTeXinterchartoks\fchar\fchar{\kern10pt}

ffoo difficult safe

\end{document}
```

So for your problem it becomes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX}]{Linux Libertine O}
\XeTeXinterchartokenstate=1
\newXeTeXintercharclass\tchar
\XeTeXcharclass`t=\tchar
\XeTeXinterchartoks\tchar\tchar{\kern0pt}

\begin{document}
rotten fisticuffs
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great alternative to the `selnolig` package for XeLaTeX. It could also be an alternative answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86593/suppression-of-a-ligature-in-xelatex).