# Missing "tt" Ligature

Tags: ligatures

I'm getting bitten by the unfortunate fact that most TeX fonts have an "ff" ligature, but no "tt" ligature.  In my field of research, we often denote logical truth by `\textbf{tt}` and falsehood by `\textbf{ff}`.  Due to the missing-ligature problem, these look quite different.

Now I could surely disable the "ff" ligature in this case, but I find that `\textbf{ff}` looks considerably better than `\textbf{f{}f}`.  I can also create a poor-man's "tt" ligature by `\textbf{t\hspace{-1pt}t}`, but the good value of `-1pt` varies depending on the font size.

How can I consistently enable a ligature in `\textbf{tt}` so that this automatically looks good in all font sizes?

(I'm currently using `lmodern`, but'd prefer a universal answer.)

Comment: I'm certainly not a font expert, but I don't believe `lmodern` has a tt ligature. Unless you want to design one, I think your best bet is using a font that has the ligature. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153071/two-t-characters-next-to-each-other-form-one-tt-glyph has an example where the questioner wants to not have a tt ligature. You could try that font.

Comment: `\textbf{t$\!$t}` seems to work for `lmodern`, but he result is poor for `palatino`.

Comment: One of the reasons a 'tt' ligature gives trouble in PDF is the absence of a defined unicode codepoint for that ligature. Perhaps that's also why that ligature is rare in fonts

Comment: The Linux Libertine font offers a `tt` ligature.

Comment: Several fonts don't have an “ff” ligature, notably Palatino or Utopia.